# How to create a new window in electron.js when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to create an electron.js app. The first window that opens should be a login window. But now I have the problem that I can't manage that when I press the login button the new main window opens.

At the moment I always get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at createBrowserWindow (login.js:16)
at HTMLFormElement. (login.js:9)

Here is my main.js file

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')


function createLoginWin() {
    const loginWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 500,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images/command.png'),
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload_login.js')
        }
    })
    
    loginWindow.loadFile('./src/index.html');
    loginWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
}


// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createLoginWin()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

It is basically the file from the electron.js documentation.

Here is my html file:

```
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" id="username_in">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password_in">
            <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="./login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my login.js file:

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form')

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const test = document.getElementById('container')
    test.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    console.log('TestHTML')
    createBrowserWindow();
    console.log('TestHTML2')
    
}); 

function createBrowserWindow() {
    console.log('TestJS1')
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    console.log('TestJS2')
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile('./index.html')
    win.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form')

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const test = document.getElementById('container')
    test.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    console.log('TestHTML')
    createBrowserWindow();
    console.log('TestHTML2')
    
}); 

function createBrowserWindow() {
    console.log('TestJS1')
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    console.log('TestJS2')
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile('./index.html')
    win.show()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).